# UIView.beginAnimations context - Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview, swift

I'm having trouble getting a UIView (UIButton) to animate in Swift. Can anyone help? Here is my code. I'm mainly having trouble with the method [UIView.beginAnimations]. It requires me to pass in a String and a CMutableVoidPointer. This currently crashes. Thanks

```
    var newCenter:CGPoint = CGPointMake(playAgainButton.center.x, playAgainButton.center.y + 200)
    [UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)]
    [UIView.setAnimationDuration(1.0)]
    playAgainButton.center = newCenter
    [UIView.commitAnimations]
```

Comment: block-based animation since iOS4, please...

Comment: If you'd looked at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/beginAnimations:context:) before asking the question, you'd have known Apple recommends you use different API. Also, why are you using square brackets around your Swift method calls?

Answer (score 6):

Change code below. It must work in Swift

```
    var newCenter:CGPoint = CGPointMake(playAgainButton.center.x, playAgainButton.center.y + 200)
    UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(1.0)
    playAgainButton.center=newCenter
    UIView.commitAnimations()
```

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be using that method to do view animations. Apple has recommended doing block based UIView animations since iOS 4. The block base equivalent that you want looks like this in Swift:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0) {
    playAgainButton.center = CGPointMake(playAgainButton.center.x, playAgainButton.center.y + 200)
}
```

Comment: And we can use the "last parameter is a closure" trick to simplify even further (removing "animations:" and placing the closure outside the parentheses).

Comment: @JeanLeMoignan Thanks I keep forgetting about that.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to use block-based version instead:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {
    playAgainButton.center.y + 200.0)    
}
```